# Spring Boot with Thymeleaf #lists.contains() does not compare equal values

Tags: spring, drop-down-menu, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to compare values in a **select input** to enable the selection `selected="selected"` of some elements.

I`m using: *Spring Boot 1.4.0* and *Thymeleaf 2.1.5*

When I check if there are values I'm sure there are in a list, always returns `false`:

```
<p th:each="modulo : ${usuario.papeis}" th:text="${modulo.nome} + ' - ' + ${meusPapeis} + ' | ' + ${meusPapeis.contains(modulo.nome)}"></p>
```

Out:

`ROLE_DASHBOARD - [ROLE_DASHBOARD, ROLE_USUARIO, ROLE_CONFIGURACOES] | false`

---

Trying another approach:

```
<p th:each="modulo : ${usuario.papeis}" th:text="${modulo.nome} + ' - ' + ${meusPapeis} + ' | ' + ${#lists.contains(meusPapeis, modulo.nome)}"></p>
```

Out:

`ROLE_DASHBOARD - [ROLE_DASHBOARD, ROLE_USUARIO, ROLE_CONFIGURACOES] | false`

---

Really, I do not know what is the problem, because when I using a literal string the return is `true`:

```
<p th:each="modulo : ${usuario.papeis}" th:text="${modulo.nome} + ' - ' + ${meusPapeis} + ' | ' + ${#lists.contains(meusPapeis, 'ROLE_DASHBOARD')}"></p>
```

Out:

`ROLE_DASHBOARD - [ROLE_DASHBOARD, ROLE_USUARIO, ROLE_CONFIGURACOES] | true`

Is there any way to accomplish this kind of comparison, using variable value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the expressions utility `#strings` to convert to string with the method `toString(stringToConvert)`. Enum is always confusing to use.
Follow the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#strings).

try `#strings.toString(modulo.nome)`. It should works.